# Using ngx-translate to display images

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I would like to use ngx-translate inside my Angular app to display a language-specific image. In my case its a Logo which is displayed in different languages and styles depending on the used language.

I did already tried with

```
        <img style="width: 100px" [attr.src]="'branding.logo' | translate" alt="" class="src" />
```

Where `branding.logo` refers to a URL of the particular logo in the web.

But Chrome displays, that it couldn't find the requested ressource at: 'https://localhost:8100/branding.logo'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`[attr.src]="'branding.logo' | translate"` is causing the literal `branding.logo` to be used. If you want to get the value from that then it should be `[attr.src]="branding.logo"` however that will not support translate.

In order to achieve a translation, you probably want to map it as `branding.logoMapByLocale` and then use the current locale to get the actual value.

Your code will look something like this:

(How to get locale from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513486/angular-how-to-get-the-current-locale-at-runtime-when-using-aot))

```js
import { LOCALE_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';

...

constructor(
  @Inject(LOCALE_ID) public locale: string
) {

  this.logoMapByLocale = {
    'en': "https://some/path/en.png",
    'fr': "https://some/path/fr.png",
}
```